# Confusing type declaration?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I haven't worked with SML in awhile and I came across this line of code:

```
type memory = string -> int;
```

Does this define 'memory' to be a function which takes a string a returns an int, or something else entirely? I've searched for a similar declaration but I can't seem to find one or figure out what it does.

When I put it into SML/NJ, I just get this:

```
- type memory = string -> int;
type memory = string -> int
```

Answer (score 8):

`memory` is not a function , it's just an abbreviation for a type that is a function that takes as input a string and returns an int.
So whenever you would like to write that something is of type `string->int` you can just write it's of type `memory`.

For example instead of writing:

```
- fun foo(f : string->int, s) = f s;
val foo = fn : (string -> int) * string -> int
```

you could write:

```
- fun foo( f: memory, s) = f s;
val foo = fn : memory * string -> int
```

Such `type` declarations can make your code more readable (e.g. instead of writing that a pair `x` is of type `int*int` like `(x: int*int)`, you can just create an abbreviation `type pair = int*int` and then you can write that `x` is of type `pair` like this `(x: pair)`).